# HTTP Certificate Pinning (HPKP) with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently building an API with Django and AWS Lambda, using [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa).

At some point in the future my API will be delivering some sensitive information, so I'm investigating SSL key pinning (HPKP). I've run into some road blocks in figuring out exactly how to implement this with AWS on Lambda.

All the guides on HPKP I've encountered have assumed that I'm operating an HTTP server where I can configure response headers. This isn't the case with AWS Lambda, but I assume the equivalent is either CloudFront or API Gateway.

[This Amazon help document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/managed-renewal.html) gives me the following advice:

> To use certificate pinning with ACM Certificates, you can do the following:
>
> - Import your own certificate into ACM and then pin your application to the imported certificate. ACM doesn't provide managed renewal for imported certificates.
> - Pin your application to the Amazon root certificates.

But offers no guidance on exactly how to:

- "pin your application to the imported certificate."
- "Pin your application to the Amazon root certificates."

Is the documentation suggesting my Django application itself should return responses with the HPKP headers? Or is there a better way of achieving this through CloudFront/API Gateway?

Comment: *"...assumed that I'm operating an HTTP server where I can configure response headers. This isn't the case with AWS Lambda..."*  How are the Lambda functions being invoked, and who is invoking them, from where?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the lambda functions are invoked from AWS API Gateway with Zappa (a link to Zappa is in the question).

Comment: API Gateway allows you to [set HTTP headers in the method response](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html), and you can either extract them from the integration response, or just set static values... which is what you're talking about needing, with pinning.  As you indicated that you are using API Gateway, it isn't clear what you're asking in that regard, since custom response headers are built-in functionality... unless it is about how to configure this aspect of API-GW using Zappa, which is something with which I am unfamiliar.

Comment: It isn't surprising that the docs don't tell you more about how to pin to your imported cert or pin to the Amazon root, because it's nothing specific to ACM. Understand the implications and logistics of HPKP, and the question answers itself... but absent that, giving you the "steps" would be a significant disservice. 
HPKP is risky: *"Deploying Public Key Pinning (PKP) safely will require operational and organizational maturity due to the risk that hosts may make themselves unavailable by pinning to a set of SPKIs that becomes invalid.*" -- [RFC-7469](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7469).

Comment: I do understand the risks of cert pinning, but it is a security feature that it's necessary for my API to implement. I was really expecting cert pinning to be a documented feature of either ACM or API GW. Given that it looks like it isn't, I guess my options are either to use custom HTTP response headers in API GW, or to have my application explicitly return the `Public-Key-Pins` header.